# How paths working on Yii

Tags: php, url, path, yii

How paths working on Yii?
For example code below is places in

```
/webapp/views/project/view.php:

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$issueDataProvider,
'itemView'=>'/issue/_view',
)); ?>
```

my structure:

```
/webapp
 /component
   /controller.php
 /controllers
   /ProjectControllers
 /views
   /project/view
   /issue/_view
```

My question is how

```
'itemView'=>'/issue/_view'
```

works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find description [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#getViewFile-detail).

> ... the corresponding view file based on the following criteria:
>
> - absolute view within a module: the view name starts with a single slash '/'. In this case, the view will be searched for under the
>     currently active module's view path. If there is no active module, the
>     view will be searched for under the application's view path.
> - absolute view within the application: the view name starts with double slashes '//'. In this case, the view will be searched for under
>     the application's view path. This syntax has been available since
>     version 1.1.3.
> - aliased view: the view name contains dots and refers to a path alias. The view file is determined by calling
>     YiiBase::getPathOfAlias(). Note that aliased views cannot be themed
>     because they can refer to a view file located at arbitrary places.
> - relative view: otherwise. Relative views will be searched for under the currently active controller's view path.